# Why is my anaconda prompt showing this error?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\vishn\Desktop\Stock-Price-Prediction-LSTM-master\StockPricePrediction.py", line 14, in StockPricePrediction
    from keras.models import Sequential
ImportError: No module named keras.models
```

Comment: Please, format your code. As to your question, looks like a missing dependency (or incorrect `PYTHONPATH`)?

Comment: You haven't downloaded keras. `pip install keras`